# using size() to return the number of elements currently in my class (c++)

Tags: c++

I'm currently writing this program and i have no idea how to use the `size()` method to return the number of values.

I have to create a class called `IntSet`, which represents a mathematical **Set of Integers** using the following data members:

1. A pointer to int that will point to a dynamically allocated array
   which holds the values currently in in `IntSet`
2. An **Int** that holds the current size of the `array` (it will need
       to be updated whenever the `add()` method because of `array` resize
3. An **Int** which holds the number of values currently in the
       `IntSet` (it will need to be updated in the `add()` and `remove()`
       methods

So far I've created a `constructor` and `destructor` and after doing the other methods I'm completely stumped on this one.

**Header:**

```
class IntSet
{
public:
    IntSet(); //Constructor
    ~IntSet(); //Destructor
    int size(); 
    bool isEmpty();
    bool contains();
    void add(double number);
    void remove(double number);

private:
    int* ptr; //pointer to the array
    int sizeOfArray; //current size of the array
    int currentValue; //number of values currently in IntSet
}
```

and the main code so far:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "IntSet.hpp"

IntSet::IntSet()
{
    sizeOfArray = 10;
    currentValue = 0;
    int* ptr = new int[10];
}

IntSet::~IntSet()
{
    delete ptr;
}
```

So how would I even begin to use the `size()` method here?

Comment: `return sizeOfArray;` Just do it...

Comment: @LogicStuff that would give the wrong answer. sizeOfArray is actually the capacity of the IntSet, Size() is probably supposed to return the number of values in the IntSet.

Comment: We don't know how OP uses it, and even OP doesn't.

Comment: so make another variable `numberOfElements`, increment it when `add` is called and decrement it when `remove` is called (like you already said). and then make a `size` function with `return numberOfElements`

Comment: You have some other issues with your code: `delete` should be `delete[]` since you are deleting an array. Also, include statements do not need a semicolon at the end. Besides that as others have said. Just implement `size()` such that it returns `currentValue`.

Comment: Also, your constructor isn't assigning the array to the member `ptr`, it is creating a **separate** variable named `ptr` and assigning the array to that!

Comment: ahh omg thank you evan! how do i fix the ptr part? :(

Answer (score 1):

if currentValue is indeed the number of values in the intSet as your comment claims, than size() can simply return currentValue.

Comment: So do I not have to include size() at all in my .cpp file?

Comment: @cdante What did I say that sounded anything like that? Of course you have to include size(), its your class, you have to define the functions.

Answer (score 0):

Size is the number of element in your set.
At first, you should init it with value 0

Every you add new element successful, increase current size by 1
Every you remove element successful, decrease current size by 1
Method size(), you only need return current size of your set

Answer (score 0):

From the specification you have given, currentValue holds the number of values in your set so you would define the following in your .cpp file.

```
int IntSet::size() const
{
    return currentValue;
}
```

Keep in mind that you will need to increment/decrement this value whenever you add/remove an element to/from your set.

Comment: ah, thank you so much man. you're all such a big help this is insane <3